# How to use the factor(f) syntax in dplyr/ forcats package in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, forcats

I am trying to do something very simple, which is use the forcats package in R to work with factors. I have a dataframe with some factor variables, one of which is gender, and I'm simply trying to count the occurrence of the variables using fct_count. The syntax is shown in the documentation as `fct_count(f)` (what could be easier!).

I'm trying to do this the dplyr way, using the pipe operator instead of the $ syntax to access the variables, but it doesn't seem to work. Am I just fundamentally misunderstanding the syntax?

```
pid <- c('id1','id2','id3','id4','id5','id6')
gender <- c('Male','Female','Other','Male','Female','Female')
df <- data.frame(pid, gender)
df <- as.tibble(df)
df
```

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  pid   gender
  <chr> <fct> 
1 id1   Male  
2 id2   Female
3 id3   Other 
4 id4   Male  
5 id5   Female
6 id6   Female
```

```
# This throws an error
df %>%
  mutate(gender = as.factor(gender)) %>%
  fct_count(gender) # Error: `f` must be a factor (or character vector).
```

```
# This works but doesn't use the nice dplyr select syntax
fct_count(df$gender)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  f          n
  <fct>  <int>
1 Female     3
2 Male       2
3 Other      1
```

Where am I going wrong? New to dplyr and sorry for such a daft question but I can't seem to find a basic example anywhere!

Comment: Add `%>% select(gender)` before the final line

Comment: Hi Oliver, thanks, this works :-) So do you have to select the column every time before passing it to the function? Seems a bit redundant to me

Comment: The function expressly asks for the factor to be passed to it, so why would you have to select it as well?

Comment: Can you please put your response as an answer so I can mark it as answered

Comment: However I don't understand why the pipe isn't after select(gender), and if I include it, I still get an error ...

Comment: You don't want to `select` you want to `pull` see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fct_count` takes a vector that is of type factor or char, it isn't especially aware of tibbles and dataframes.  So the simplest pipe would be...

```r
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

df %>%
   pull(gender) %>%
   fct_count 
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   f          n
#>   <fct>  <int>
#> 1 Female     3
#> 2 Male       2
#> 3 Other      1
```

Your data

```r
pid <- c('id1','id2','id3','id4','id5','id6')
gender <- c('Male','Female','Other','Male','Female','Female')
df <- data.frame(pid, gender)
df <- tibble::as_tibble(df)
df
```

Comment: thanks, this makes sense. I have the same problem with levels:   ```nitros_sub %>%
  select(gender) %>%
  levels(gender) # This does not work```. 
```levels(nitros_sub %>% select(gender)) # This does not work```. 

```nitros_sub %>%
  select(gender)
  levels(gender) # This does not work```
  
```nitros_sub %>%
  pull(gender) %>%
  levels() # This works ``` I guess I was getting my classes mixed up, assuming that select(gender) returns a factor variable but indeed it does not. I guess I'll stick with ```levels(df$gender)``` and ```fct_count(df$gender)``` which seems alot simpler!

Comment: Correct, it would be nice if `fct_count` or the others understood a data pronoun but they don't so pull gets you where you need to be.  `select` still would require the function to understand .data$variable which they don't.  Actually `pull` is very handy for many simple functions like `table` so a good tool for your toolbox.  Once upon a time select did return based upon the number of columns selected but now it always returns a dataframe or tibble.

Comment: You're right, thanks for taking the time to answer and explain :-)

Answer (score 0):

you could just use group_by and n()

```
pid <- c('id1','id2','id3','id4','id5','id6')
gender <- c('Male','Female','Other','Male','Female','Female')
df <- data.frame(pid, gender)
df <- tibble::tibble(df)


df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(gender) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(cnt_gender = n()) %>% 
  dplyr::ungroup()
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look - yes I could, but there is a simple function in the package to count the variables and I just want to know how to use it given the syntax in the documentation. That's what fct_count(f) does in one line, but I'm doing something wrong